# How to add a list of booleans per user to a django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

In addition to the basic user model I have a second custom model in my django app. This model is called a **challenge**. I want this challenge object to contain a list of booleans for each user where I can store which users have completed this challenge.

#### This list must be able to do the following things:

- Whenever a new user is added, each existing challenge object needs to get a new boolean which is set to false.
- Whenever a user is deleted the corresponding booleans in each challenge must be removed also.
- Whenever a user completes a challenge the list inside the challenge object must be updated.

How do I do this?

I think I need to use some sort of ForeignKey of ManyToOne relationship, but I really have no idea how to go about this. I added a ManyToMany field and gave it the paramter User, but that only gave me a list of all Users where I could’t remove any of the users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that having list of booleans is a bad idea, I would do something like:

```
class Challenge(models.Model):
   succeeded_users = models.ManyToManyField(User, verbose_name="Users who have completed this challenge"
    ...
```

So whenever user completed challenge you cann add him/her to  succeeded_users list:

```
some_challenge.succeeded_users.add(some_user)
```

If you want to get all users that completed challenge:

```
some_challenge.succeeded_users.all()
```

If you want to get all users that havent completed challenge you can do for example:

```
completed_uses_id = some_challenge.succeeded_users.values("ids")
uncompleted_uses = Challenge.objects.exclude(id__in=completed_uses_id )
# or 
uncompleted_uses = Challenge.objects.difference(some_challenge.succeeded_users.all())
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Vlad, this unfortunately gives me a field filled with all existing users where I can't add or remove any. I’ve attached an image to the original question. Was this the outcome you expected or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Those are not all users, you can click on them, and they will be selected, now,on your image nobody is selected so nobody has completed challenge

Comment: Oh, my bad, so sorry for misunderstanding. This is exactly what I wanted, thanks Vlad! :)

Comment: No problem, not very intuitive interface for this field ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a separate model for the challenge, where you can use a foreign key to reference each user. Use on_delete=models.CASCADE to automatically delete the object if the user is deleted.

```
class Challenge(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    iscomplete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Whenever an user completes the challenge, you can acess the challenge object with the matching user ID and update the boolean value as True

If you want to have multiple challenges, you could create one model which stores all the challenges, and have an additional relational model which will show which users have completed which challenges.

```
class Challenge(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"

class Complete(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    challenge = models.ForeignKey(Challenge,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user} completed {self.challenge}"
```